# Undefined variable - Passing a variable through the url

Tags: php, html, url

I get cant get my variable to echo on the page even though it shows in the URL. Here is the link that passes it

```
<a href='eventform.php?$eventname'>
```

And the code to get it on a other page:

```
$eventname = 0;
if (isset($_GET['eventname'])) {
$eventname = $_GET['eventname'];
}
echo $_GET['eventname'];
```

It displays the 0 but not the Mountain 2012 which is in the url at the top. Please help me with this problem

Am i displaying it correctly on the other page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need:

- To give it a name in the query string
- To sanitise the data for the URI
- To sanitise the URI for the HTML

Thus:

```
<a href='eventform.php?eventname=<?php
    echo htmlspecialchars( urlencode( $eventname ) );
?>'>
```

Comment: It gets rid of the error but it still does not echo the var on the page with my isset code

Comment: also the url comes out like this: sportevent/eventform.php?eventname=%3C?php%20%20%20%20echo%20htmlspecialchars(%20urlencode(%20Marathon%202012%20)%20);?%3E

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to put eventname= in your url such as:

```
<a href="eventform.php?eventname=<?php echo $eventname; ?>">
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<a href='eventform.php?<?php=$eventname?>'>
```

Or:

```
<a href='eventform.php?<?php echo $eventname?>'>
```

Although you might want:

```
<a href='eventform.php?eventname=<?php echo $eventname?>'>
```

^^sets `$_GET['eventname']` to `$eventname`

Comment: be carefull with echo like that. It might be disabled in the php.ini.

Comment: @Topener `Since PHP 5.4.0, <?= is always available.` http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag